# Calculating average for each Reward Type

Tags: sql, postgresql

For each reward type, I am trying to calculate the average number of times rewards of that type has been included in a deposit. A constraint on it is that deposits that do not include reward type don't contribute to the average for that type instead of 0.

Below is the schema:

```
rewards(rewardId, rewardType, rewardValue);
deposit(depositId, depositDate, customerId);
details(depositId, rewardsId, numDeposit);
```

Here is my query:

```
select r.rewardsId, avg(dep.depositId) 
from deposit dep join details det 
    on dep.depositId = det.depositId join rewards r 
    on r.rewardsId = det.rewardsId  
group by r.rewardsId;
```

The answer I get doesn't seem right since the average is very high but when I count it manually, I get around 2 for each rewardType. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want the average of an id column. 
 That just doesn't make sense.

You may just want `count(*)`:

```
select r.rewardsId, count(*) as num_rewards 
from details det join
     rewards r 
     on r.rewardsId = det.rewardsId  
group by r.rewardsId;
```

From what I can tell, you don't need the `deposit` table.  The deposit id is in the details.

Or, if you want rewards per deposit:

```
select r.rewardsId,
       count(*) * 1.0 / count(distinct det.depositId) as num_rewards 
from details det join
     rewards r 
     on r.rewardsId = det.rewardsId  
group by r.rewardsId;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that calculate all the times a reward of a certain type has been included? I want to find the average

Comment: Did you try the second query?

Comment: I just did, and it outputs just 1 for all 5 rewards type

Comment: @tirth96 . . . Possibly due to integer division.

Comment: that could be it. Do you know how to allow decimals in that case?

Comment: @tirth96 . . . I changed the answer.  I just multiply by 1.0.  But of course `::numeric` would also work in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to count only deposits that do include reward type, then you can count them like this:

```
select t.rewardsId, avg(t.counter) from (
  select 
    r.rewardsId, 
    sum(case when det.rewardsId is null then 0 else 1 end) counter
  from deposit dep join details det 
  on dep.depositId = det.depositId join rewards r 
  on r.rewardsId = det.rewardsId  
  group by r.rewardsId, dep.depositId
) t
group by t.rewardsId
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nullif(dep.depositId, 0)` to convert the zeros to `null`, which  will not be accounted for in the average calculations.

Consider the following:

```
select  avg(val)            as avg_all, 
        avg(nullif(val, 0)) as avg_nonzero
from    (values
            (2), (4), (6), (0), (8), (0), (10)
        ) v(val)
```

which returns:

```
avg_all           |avg_nonzero       |
------------------|------------------|
4.2857142857142857|6.0000000000000000|
```

See [nullif documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF)